# Disable weather.com in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, big-sur

In Safari if I type a place name or place name + weather and press enter, I get taken to the weather at weather.com

[image]

[image]

How can I make it do a google search instead?

Comment: I can't repro. If I do that I get a drop-menu with the weather, but if I hit Enter I get a regular Google search, even though this is one of those things Google like to answer for you right at the top of the page. https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1AjW.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable this in Safari Preferences

[image]

Comment: Does that translate roughly as "Include Safari suggestions"? I have that switched on & still get to Google.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes it does. If I tick off both "Include search engine suggestions" and "include safari suggestions" I get the behaviour shown in the question (with DDG and with Google). If I untick the second option it searches as expected

Comment: If I switch both off I lose the helpful little drop telling me the 'simple' answer, but I still get Google search if I hit enter - https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOZfv.png (I used a different town just so it wouldn't remember what I did last time) Hmmm… I wonder whether the OP has it stored in "Manage Websites" on the Quick Search??

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't have weather.com listed there

Comment: Me neither. I can't figure out what triggers that. Going to weather.com doesn't add it, nor does it change my search bar result except that it now adds the history item at the bottom, as I've now been there before. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ6m9.png

Comment: Turning off the top option "Include Safari suggetsions" worked for me. All my bottom three are still checked